# How to copy local git repository from local machin

Tags: git

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my virtualBox , where I downloaded Git repository(Android source code). I want to take copy the git repository to same local machine.

If I use cp -r cmd symbolic link files are not copied to destination.
If I use cp -Lr cmd following error comes

cp cannot state /path/filename : No such files of directory.

How can I copy full content of git repository..?

Regards,
Kishore P

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings in virtualbox and set up shared folder between host and guest. Then you will be able to copy from virtual machine to mounted folder, and whatever you copy there will be available in host as well. You will need sudo privilege to copy the files inside VM, because shared folder is owned by root

[image]

Comment: Please explain the downvote

Comment: +1 for the folder I think it come from there, but I don't have to use root to copy anything ;)

Answer (score 0):

`-L` follows the links in the source to find the file to copy instead of copying the links themselves.
You may use `cp -a` which covers all cases, plus the preservation of a couple of other attributes.